# Comparing two sets of P values

Tags: distributions, p-value

I have two sets of P-values. Each set contains about 1500 P-values that are computed by different versions -i.e. slightly different algorithms- of the same software. These two versions used the same input data and the P-values have the same meaning, but are slightly different. The algorithms test for an enrichment of certain cell types in a certain disease. Most cell types are not associated, leading to a negatively skewed distribution of P-values.

My goal is not to determine which algorithm performs the best, but I want to know whether there is a difference between the two sets of P-values. I am unsure whether it makes sense to compare two sets of P-values and if yes, how I would accomplish that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This seems like a good case for a two sample goodness of fit test

Comment: If you have an exact test with a continuous test statistic, then under $H_0,$ _-values are distributed according to a standard uniform distribution. // Can you be mote specific about what test you are doing [with what parameter[s]) and why you think P-values may not match?

Comment: I've edited the question. The P-values are not normally distributed, so I am not sure whether I can use the P-values as a way of comparing the differences between the two algorithms.

Comment: Sometimes it does make sense to compare P-values for two tests used for similar purposes. There are often several relevant ways in which to make the comparison.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would a t-test be appropiate here? Even though the data is skewed, would that be a concern considering my n? Or would a Wilcoxon test be better suited here? Or perhaps another test?

Comment: Possibly related: [The fickle P value generates irreproducible results](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.3288).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment. Let us start in the beginning. What reason do you want  p-values for? It may not be obvious that that question is even relevant, but it is. For example, the cost of an incorrect answer might be trivial or lethal in either direction but not both, false positive or false negative. So what the characteristics are of the p-value calculation should be ascertained in that context, the "What are you doing with those p-values?" question. Once that question is answered we can at least proceed to structure an answer. In a more neutral context, where the penalty of an incorrect answer is approximately balanced between false negative and false positive, one might anticipate  that the p-values that discriminate better would be preferable, that is, two tests could yield the same average probability but one of them could be useless and the other useful.

In either case, that of dissimilar or similar costs for an incorrect answer between false positive and false negative one can apply simulation studies with simulation truth data or one can collect structured truth data (where the correct answer is known), and then apply the two tests to determine which is working more appropriately for whatever the desired outcome is. I cannot think of any other way of approaching this problem, and if that is just my failure to imagine one, do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the comparison below of P-values from two 'slightly' different versions of a
test will be sufficiently similar to the comparison you have in mind, that some of my methods below will be useful in your situation.

In R, the procedure `prop.test` tests whether two binomial proportions are equal. For example if Group 1 has 12 successes out of 30 members and Group 2 has 18 successes out of 30, are the observed proportions $12/30 = 0.4$
and $18/30 = 0.6$ significantly different at the 5% level. One version
of the `prop.test` sometimes uses a 'continuity correction' in computing
the test statistic (as below); and sometimes not. One has the ability to use
the parameter `cor=F` to make sure no continuity correction is used.
There is some controversy among statisticians whether the continuity
correction is sometimes or ever appropriate.

```
prop.test(c(12,18), c(30,30))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(12, 18) out of c(30, 30)
X-squared = 1.6667, df = 1, p-value = 0.1967
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.48125135  0.08125135
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
   0.4    0.6
```

Without the continuity correction, the P-value is $0.12,$

```
prop.test(c(12,18), c(30,30), cor=F)$p.val
[1] 0.1213353
```

So here is a brief simulation to see whether the continuity correction
makes an important difference in test results. Suppose two different
people toss a fair coin 30 times, obtaining $X$ and $Y$ Heads respectively.
Does `prop.test` ever say proportions $X/30$ and $Y/30$ are significantly
different? When testing at the 5% level, the answer should be Yes: 5% of the time.

```
set.seed(120)
pv.c =replicate( 4000,prop.test(c(rbinom(1,30,1/2),
                 rbinom(1,30,1/2)),  c(30,30))$p.val)
mean(pv.c <= .05)
[1] 0.027    $ NOT 5%
summary(pv.c)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0002983 0.4215705 0.6053761 0.6364214 1.0000000 1.0000000 

set.seed(121)
pv.w =replicate( 4000, 
prop.test(c(rbinom(1,30,1/2),
          rbinom(1,30,1/2)),c(30,30),cor=F)$p.val)
mean(pv.w <= .05)
[1] 0.0525  # near 5%
summary(pv.w)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.    
0.0002249 0.2839000 0.4383235 0.4969538 0.7934282 1.0000000
```

The 'continuity-corrected version has significance level below 5%,
while the version without continuity correction significance level
nearer to the 5% level.
Descriptive statistics show lower P-values without correction

A Kolmogorov-Smirnov test shows a very highly significant difference,
but the P-value is not exact account of ties.

```
ks.test(pv.c, pv.w)

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  pv.c and pv.w
D = 0.24575, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

Warning message:
In ks.test(pv.c, pv.w) :
  p-value will be approximate in the presence of ties
```

A Wilcoxon rank sum test shows a hightly significant difference.

```
wilcox.test(pv.c, pv.w)

    Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  pv.c and pv.w
W = 9952000, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Empirical CDF (ECDF) plots show that the continuity-corrected P-values
(brown) stochastically dominate the 'uncorrected' (blue) ones (blue). [The
brown plot is below and to the right of the blue plot.]

```
plot(ecdf(pv.c), col="brown", main=hdr)
 lines(ecdf(pv.w), col="blue")
```

[image]